# Use a single site package (as exception) for a virtualenv

Tags: python, lxml, virtualenv

In a virtualenv, how can I ignore the `no-site-packages` rule for a single package?

Some background: I use virtualenv for my deployments, but these take a lot longer since I have been using `lxml`. Compiling this takes up to 15 minutes each time I reinstall for a new virtualenv. Can I make some sort of an exception for `lxml` and use the global site package? Is there any safer/more reliable option than just copying it into the new virtualenv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no, but you can do something else to solve the same problem.

The `--no-site-packages` option (which is now the default unless you specify `--system-site-packages`) controls whether or not some directories are added to [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). A given directory is either in or not, you can not discriminate only one package in that directory.

However, you can make a symbolic link to the package in the virtual environment’s `site-packages` directory. On my system:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Or more generically (using the system’s python, not the environment’s):

```
ln -s $(python -c 'import lxml, os.path; print(os.path.dirname(lxml.__file__)') ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

If you’re on a system that does not support symbolic links, copying should also work but is more fragile when the system-wide lxml is updated.

Comment: Thank you, this would work and is not even that ugly a hack :)

Comment: This doesnt weem to work with `pip`, it doesnt recognize the package as installed even though I can import it

Comment: Okay I fixed it by linking to the egg-info as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13780772/708221