# Cannot install Scipy in FreeBSD 13 with Python 3.10

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, freebsd, python-3.10

I am trying install `scipy` in `FreeBSD 13`. I have built `python 3.10` on `FreebSD 13` and managed to install `pandas`, `matplotlib` and `numpy` on a *virtual environment* which has `python 3.10`. However, when I try to install `sklearn` or `scipy` I get an error saying `scipy` could not be installed.
Here it is below for when doing `pip install scipy`. I get the same error more or less when trying to install `sklearn`.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
  Failed to build scipy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/schroter/.pymain/dataViz/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-d3nnvp2f/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-xp_669rf/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'oldest-supported-numpy; python_version!='"'"'3.7'"'"' or platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"' or platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"' or platform_python_implementation == '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.6; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' 'scipy>=1.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

My pip list is as below:

```
(dataViz) schroter@SCHROTER:~ % pip list
Package          Version
---------------- -------
cycler           0.11.0
kiwisolver       1.1.0
matplotlib       3.4.3
numpy            1.21.4
pandas           1.3.4
Pillow           8.4.0
pip              21.3.1
pyparsing        3.0.6
python-dateutil  2.8.2
pytz             2021.3
semantic-version 2.8.5
setuptools       58.5.3
setuptools-rust  0.12.1
six              1.16.0
toml             0.10.2
wheel            0.37.0
```

Would anyone be able to help me in this regards please?
Thanks & Best Regards
Schroter

Comment: `Check the logs for full command output`. You really should do that. Besides that, a quick glimpse over scipy's github and docs would worry me a bit about freebsd support (not that it's not supported, but it does not feel like a first class citizen). Most peoples trouble installing scipy comes from not following a pre-built package route because building from source is not always easy (easier on unixes). In your case, and i really don't have knowledge about freebsd, i still would recommend going for some pre-built stuff.This implies some dependencies (there is no py 3.10 package on ANY OS yet)

Comment: So, again, non-FreeBSD user speaking, i would recommend something like [this](https://www.freshports.org/science/py-scipy) which, if i interpret correctly, implies going back to Python 3.8. But this should be fine, as 3.8 is still a maintained Python release.

Comment: I wish you could find a solution to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Reuse system package

```sh
# install system-wide version in site-packages
doas pkg install py38-scipy-1.8.0
# create a virtualenv with site-packages included
python -m venv --system-site-packages .venv
```

Drawback is you'll get all packages from `site-packages`, however you can tackle that by

```sh
doas pkg install py38-scipy-1.8.0
python -m venv .venv

YOUR_PYTHON_VERSION= SET IT HERE
ln -s $(python -c 'import lxml, os.path; print(os.path.dirname(lxml.__file__)') ./.venv/lib/$YOUR_PYTHON_VERSION/site-packages
```

borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13719417

### Regular Installation (TODO)

Haven't figured out it yet, but maybe someone else will, so putting here 2 links which might be helpful

1. https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/python-scipy-with-python3-x-on-freebsd-11.59009/
2. https://reviews.freebsd.org/D23447

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to install scipy from freebsd ports? The freebsd ports contain patches to make the code compile on FreeBSD.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I do not want to do that. Would like to keep the system isolated. I want to install it in a python virtual environment. Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: Then your best bet is probably to grab the patches to the FreeBSD port and compile yourself.

Comment: For a regular python app workflow, you don't want to intermix "system" python packages with packages that are only available through pypi. It's a mess and every pythonista knows it. Python packages packaged by system vendors is bullshit, it's common knowledge. You want pipenv or poetry install your project and be done with it. I'm blaming this on SciPy being broken on FreeBSD and requiring patches.